# Reverse not the string as a whole just the word

Tags: javascript

It is rather surprising how many topics I find where someone asks how to reverse a string, and everyone responds how to reverse the string as a whole.
That is not what I want. I want to leave the words exactly where they are and only reverse each word individually.

I know how to reverse the whole string.

```
str.split(' ').reverse().join(' '); && || str.split('').reverse().join('');
                               (and/or)
```

What I need to know is how to reverse each word individually.

I want to see.

`"olleh dlrow"`

not

`"dlrow olleh"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  sentence.split(" ").map(word => word.split("").reverse().join("")).join(" ");
```

First split the sentence into a word array, map that word array to a reversed word array and join that again to a sentence. Another way:

```
  function reverseWord(sentence){
    let word = "", result = "";
    for(let char of sentence){
      if(char === " "){
        result += " " + word;
        word = "";
      } else {
       word = char + word;
      }
    }
    return result + " " + word;
 }
```